# How do I remove the rollover effect from Rubik tooltips

Tags: tooltips

I am using Rubik and the tooltips are rollovers. Generally this is fine, but for one site I need them to display with the field instead. Is there a setting to disable the rollover effect and just make it look like help text?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this theme before, but there is a checkbox on the theme settings page to toggle "Display form field descriptions inline". I believe this is what you are looking for.